# Angular7/Ionic4 - Cannot set property 'header' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I keep getting this error when using the Angular cdk for using a virtual list. Ionic 4 has an implementation, but, as Mike Hartington, from Ionic, has suggested is, for now, to use the [Angular cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) so that's what i have done and now what I am trying to do is add a header functionality as I am trying to show a list of contacts and would like what a contacts list looks like: a header of "A" and all the people with last names starting with "A" are under. etc.
here is the html:

#### component.html

```html
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
    class="scroll-viewport"
    #scroll
    [itemSize]="itemSize"
    minBufferPx="900"
    maxBufferPx="1350"
  >
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-divider *ngIf="header?.length"> {{ header }} </ion-item-divider> <!-- ERROR HERE -->
      <ion-item *cdkVirtualFor="let contact of contactList; trackBy: trackByFn" (click)="openProfile(contact)">
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start" class="rounded">
          <img [src]="contact.profilePicture" />
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label position="stacked"
          ><ion-text color="primary">
            <h4>{{ contact.lastNames }}, {{ contact.firstNames }}</h4></ion-text
          ></ion-label
        >
        <ion-label position="stacked"> {{ contact.specialty }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

#### component.ts

```js
export class ContactsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public contacts: Contact[];
  public header: string;

  constructor() {
    this.header = 'A';
  }

  public trackByFn(recordIndex: number, record: Contact): number {
    let i: string;
    const char = record.lastNames[0].toUpperCase().replace('À', 'A');
    if (char !== i) {
      i = record.lastNames[0];
      this.header = i;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I've been trying all ways of defining it where directly under the `trackByFn` saying `this.header = 'A'` but still the same issue. as well as underneath the class declaration just putting `public header = 'A';` just to see if it will read it in the {{header}} part of the html. But, the issue is the same saying that it is undefined. I've also tried moving the placement of the `<ion-item-divider>` but still the same issue.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to remove "public" ?

Comment: hey @Sam the issue isn't with public because all it does is explicitly say who has access to this. removing `public` gives it, inherently, `public`.